# Find parent with defined attribute wuth LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parent

I have variable XElement *content* =

```
        "...
         <item text="Name-1" id="1" segment="1" secret-id="Find-Me">
            <item text="Name-1-1" id="1.1">
               <item text="Name-1-1-1" id="1.1.1" />
               <item text="Name-1-1-2" id="1.1.2" />
            </item>
         </item>
         ..."
```

I have also an item with *id = 1.1.2*

I need to find the first parent of this item which has attribute *segment="1"* and get its *secret-id*

How to do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the "closest ancestor"?

```
string secretId = element.Ancestors()
                         .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("segment") == "1")
                         .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("secret-id"))
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will be null if either:

- There are no ancestors with an attribute segment="1"
- The element with that attribute has no secret-id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
item.Ancestors().Select(p => p.Attribute("secret-id")).First(a => a != null)
```